# Popup with 3 buttons - Onclick event problem AJAX , ASP.net project

Tags: asp.net, ajax

For Save button, I have a popup which has 3 buttons inside., Yes, No and Cancel. Yes should call a function and update 2 tables in the database and No should update just one table and cancel should not make any changes in the page.

Used code for popup

```
<table id="pnlPopupMerchantUpdate" runat="server" style="display:none">
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
            <table width="350" height="80" class="warningPopup">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- <img src="images/warning_blue.gif" alt="Warning" /> -->
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left" style="padding-left: 75px; padding-top: 10px;">
                        Do you wish to update the Location Information as well.
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="4">
                        <input id="btnYesMerchant" type="button" value="Yes" class="popupButton" causesvalidation="true" onclick="btnYessave_Click"/> 
                        <input id="btnNoMerchant" type="button" value="No" class="popupButton" causesvalidation="true" onclick="btnNosave_Click" /> 
                        <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" class="popupButton"/>                            
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here if the user clicks Yes it has to update Location info along with COmpany Info. If No is clicked, just Company Info. Cancel will not modify anything. There is a function UpdateMerchantInfo() which has to modify according to what is called, i mean yes or No.

I have used Onclick events for both Yes and NO but the problem here is, Yes should call its onclick event before getting into UpdatemerchantInfo(), the same way with NO.

In UpdateMerchantInfo(), i want to use if loop and do accordingly.

I hope i am clear!!

Thank you much!

Comment: Can you please clarify how you're creating the popup, the behavior you're expecting, and what you're actually seeing?

You're saying that you get the popup "the way you want", but you're also saying that it's calling a "Save" method rather than an OnClick handler?

Comment: My bad! i edited my question now! You can now take a look and help me. Thanks Sir!!

Comment: It sounds like you can just call UpdateMerchantInfo() from btnYessave_Click() and btnNosave_Click(), in that case.

Maybe another way of putting this...what is it doing that you're not expecting, and what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use popup control extender in ajax. Will find more details [Here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx)

It has sufficient tags to suport your requirements.
You have to just create a contol(using tags) and in popup controlid set id of popup. Using this method you can define different eventhandlers.